# should you let search result page to be indexed

Tags: robots.txt, google-index, noindex

I have a pages of a catalogs, which contains a list of keywords of all products inside that catalogs, and I want to create a link from those keywords to a search page.

For example, if the page contains a keyword of `television 24", electronic, sound system`, if user click on each of the keyword, it will open a page `/search/television 24"` for example.

Should I let those pages indexed or should I block it with `robots.txt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Google's Webmaster Guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769?hl=en&topic=1724121&ctx=topic):

> Use robots.txt to prevent crawling of search results pages or other
>   auto-generated pages that don't add much value for users coming from
>   search engines.

More often than not, these pages can come across as "spammy" and of low value.

Comment: is it ok to have the `meta tags noindex, follow` for that page? and what will happen to all page or seo if there's already a `search results page` that's been indexed? And how to determine if it `don't add much value for users coming from search engines`

Comment: `noindex, follow` would be perfect, in my personal opinion. If search results already exist in the index, they'll inevitably be removed as time goes on.

Comment: You could just use canonical links and let Google what it thinks is better for your users. Sometimes search results pages are useful for what people want.